# Rewrite rules for .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, webserver, frontend

I have a basic question about the .htaccess file.

Currently mine consists of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Redirect all links to the hypertext transfer protocol secure (https) of the website.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

Rewrite all .html files without their file extension.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ /$1/index.html [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.+/)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301]
```

Remove the index.html from site URLs. **Should I remove the file extension (.html) because of the 2nd rule?**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Self-explanatory. **Should I remove the file extension here as well?**

And overall - **is the code correct, is this the way it should look like in my .htaccess file?**

*I appreciate your help.*

Comment: Why don't you simply try out it?

Comment: The answers to both questions is: "no". Why? Are those physical files stored with a "file name extension" or without? You certainly _could_ rewrite requests targetting these files in two steps, but _why_ ? It only get's slower. You need to differ between rewriting _external_ requests and _internal_ redirections.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.]+)$ $1.html [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

The **index.html remove from URLs** rule was useless, because I changed my links in the html part:

```
<a href="index.html">Homepage</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="/">Homepage</a>
```

and analogical:

```
<a href="en/index.html">English Homepage</a>
```

to:

```
<a href="en">English Homepage</a>
```